# Not receiving ipn response from PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Im having problems with PayPal and IPN on my website and have tried loads of things with no joy.

What i am attempting to do:

Receive notification of payment from PayPal and then update database with details from variables.

Whats working:

- Using the IPN simulator from PayPal sandbox to simulate a transaction and sending the information to my listener WORKS and database gets updated.
- purchasing items through the website works on sandbox and with out sandbox.

what does not work:

- after purchase on website, listener does not receive information back from PayPal either using sandbox or normal and there for database does not get updated.

What i am using:

- I am using simpleCartjs for my cart

Listener file is:

```
$p = new paypal_class;             

if ($p->validate_ipn() && !empty($p->ipn_data['payment_status']) && $p->ipn_data['payment_status'] == 'Completed') {


                $mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
                $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
                $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
                $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
                $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
                $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
                $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
                $payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
                $address_name = $_POST['address_name'];
                $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
                $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
                $address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
                $address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
                $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
                $mc_shipping = $_POST['mc_shipping'];
                $mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
                $ipn_track_id = $_POST['ipn_track_id'];



$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT into orders (mc_gross, payer_id, payment_date, first_name, last_name, payer_email, payment_status, payer_status, address_name, address_country, address_zip, address_state, address_city, address_street, mc_shipping, mc_currency, ipn_track_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");    
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssss", $mc_gross, $payer_id, $payment_date, $first_name, $last_name, $payer_email, $payment_status, $payer_status, 
$address_name, $address_country, $address_zip, $address_state, 
$address_city, 
$address_street, $mc_shipping, $mc_currency, $ipn_track_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


}
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue please? cant seem to get this working no matter what i try. I have IPN enabled in my business paypal account.

Thank you

Comment: Forgot to add... I looked on paypal notifications and it displays after purchase code 200 and sent

Comment: This is the display in paypal HTTP response code
What's this?
200

Delivery status
Sent

No. of retries
0

Comment: anyone have any clues please? still really struggling and sending me mad